# Passing a value from one Sharepoint page to a table in a second Sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint-2013, cell

I made a table on a SharePoint page using a webpart/snippet and some coding. My goal is to add code to pull a value for a couple of the cells in the table from another SharePoint page using a QueryString. My issue, I'm newer to SharePoint, and not sure how to set up the page that I'm pulling the information from. Ultimately, the page with the table will only be editable by a few owners. The page with the info to populate the cells will have multiple people that have the permission to edit the page to update their information daily. Now, here is where  I'm not sure how to proceed. I don't want the users, most of which have no coding experience, to have to deal with entering their daily values into a coded snippet. But I'm not sure how to call the value from randomly entered data on a SharePoint page line. I believe it is SharePoint 2013. I can insert a table using the SharePoint feature rather than a snippet code, and that would be easily editable for the users. But Then I'm right back with not being sure how to call the information. I believe I can come up with the code once I figure out how I need to set up page with the information, but can edit the question as deemed necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below thread

There are many way to send data from one page to another page

Query string is better if you are using table, redirect the link using custom code else follow the below link it might be help you to clarify or achieve something

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b9d62eb1-57ed-4251-975d-13f9ae35f29f/how-to-pass-query-string-parameter-from-sharepoint-list-view-web-part-?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

have a nice day

Regards
Vinod